# How can I answer answer some question with 'y' in ansible with expect?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to destroy docker containers and images and I need to confirm destruction by entering 'y'.  I've tried a few tweaks based on various questions here but I still haven't managed to get it to work.  Can someone please advise as to how I can answer the question 'This will delete all containers and data, are you sure? (y/n)' with 'y'?

Here is my current attempt.

```
- name: Destroy containers and images
  expect:
    command: kolla host destroy all --includedata --removeimages
    responses:
      This will delete all containers and data, are you sure? (y/n):
        - y
```

The following version shows ok but doesn't actually do it.

```
- name: Destroy containers and images
shell: |
  spawn kolla host destroy all --includedata --removeimages
  expect "This will delete all containers and data, are you sure? (y/n)"
  send "y"
args:
  executable: /usr/bin/expect
```

Obviously all works fine from shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working solution is responses altered as shown.  I also had to drop the '--includedata' option in the command even though it should work; works in shell.  It's not so applicable in my setup so not going to waste anymore time on it.

```
- name: Destroy containers and images
  expect:
    command: kolla host destroy --removeimages all
    responses:
      (?i)This will delete all containers and data, are you sure? (y/n): "y"
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [kolla-ansible](https://docs.openstack.org/kolla-ansible/latest/user/operating-kolla.html)?
This will help you:

> **kolla-ansible -i INVENTORY destroy** is used to clean up containers and
>   volumes in the cluster.

Comment: I'm not strictly using Kolla's kolla so the command option does not apply in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I got it to partially work as follows.

```
- expect:
    #command: kolla host destroy all --includedata --removeimages
    command: kolla host destroy all
    responses:
      (?i)This will delete all containers and data, are you sure? (y/n): "y"
```

I just need to figure out how to include the options.